# how to configure gitorious to trigger jenkins build hook

Tags: jenkins, gitorious

I'm new to using gitorious and wish to trigger a jenkins (also a newbie) build on push . What is the simplest example to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be managed:

- by a [script called `custom-post-receive`](https://gitorious.org/gitorious/mainline/source/4f77069d0c4c65eba5da35223cedddb90fb84611%3adata/hooks/custom-post-receive.sample), in the data/hooks folder of your gitorious installation on the server.
- or [by WebHooks](https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/WebHooks) (also on the Gitorious server side)

Since [issue 99](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/99/files), Jenkins will be listening for those Gitorious hooks.
The [Gitorious plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gitorious+Plugin) for Jenkins also manage that hook.